# Angular 4 Typescript multi pipe value

Tags: angular, typescript, filter, pipe, components

I've created a pipe 'filterBy' and I want to use it on my application. Almost everything works good, but I want to use this pipe for 5 properties, and I have no abilities to understand how to do it. I will try to explain you what I mean.

**My pipe**

```
import { Injectable, Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'filterBy',
  pure: false
})

@Injectable()
export class FilterBy implements PipeTransform {
  transform( array: Array<any>, filterField: string, filterValue: string, filterField2: string, filterValue2: any): Array<any> {
    if (!array) return [];
    return array.filter(item => item[filterField] === filterValue);
  }
}
```

**products.component.html**

```
<div class="col-sm-1 lessmargins" *ngFor="let product of products | filterBy: 'condition': 'new'"
```

It works good, but my product have a properties like condition, prices etc. 
For example I would like to show products with 'condition' : 'new' and 'condition' : 'used' and I don't know how to do it. 
I tried to run it like that: 
**products.component.html**

```
*ngFor="let product of products | filterBy: {'condition': 'new'} && {'condition' : 'used'}"
```

But it doesn't work :(
is that something wrong with my pipe?
Could someone explain me?

Comment: Advanced logic like that is probably better off at the component (view model) level than in the markup FWIW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add all the properties you want to filter on to an array and pass that array to the pipe. You can then just loop through the array of properties and check that all match. Below is an example:

A class for your filters:

```
export class Filter {
    public name: string;
    public value: any;
}
```

And then just create new filters and push to an array of filters. Use the array in your pipe instead:

```
<div class="col-sm-12" *ngFor="let product of products | filterBy: filters">
</div>
```

And then loop the array of filters in your pipe:

```
import { Injectable, Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { Filter } from './filter';

@Pipe({
  name: 'filterBy',
  pure: false,
})
export class FilterBy implements PipeTransform {
  transform( array: Array<any>, filters: Array<Filter>): Array<any> {
    if (!array) return [];
    if (!filters) return array;

    return array.filter(item => matchAll(item, filters));
  }
}

function matchAll(item: any, filters: Array<Filter>): boolean {
  let valid = true;
  for (const filter of filters) {
    if (!hasKey(item, filter.name)
      || item[filter.name] !== filter.value) {
      valid = false;
      break;
    }
  }

  return valid;
}

function hasKey(item: any, keyName: string): boolean {
  return Object.keys(item).indexOf(keyName) !== -1;
}
```

Comment: It looks pretty good, but I don't know how to set 'filters'                                   value filters: Filter[] = []; Yes I know I'm so useless, you done good job thank you very much. I will try once again

Comment: Great that you could figure it out, and don’t be to hard on yourself; we have all been beginners at some point. Don’t forget to accept the answer as a solution as well